# Node_exporter --collector.systemd.unit-include regex trouble

Tags: regex, linux, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm trying to limit the systemd units that the node_exporter is gathering metrics for, and I'm having trouble with the regex. I'm using the grafana-server.service as a test on the host, but the exporter is not reporting any metrics when I introduce the regex. I've tried multiple formats but can't figure it out, this is the one I'm currently trying atm:

`ExecStart=/opt/node_exporter/node_exporter --collector.systemd.unit-include "(grafana|ssh)\.service" --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points "^/(sys|proc|dev|run|boot|host|etc)($|/)" $ARGS`

The filesystem collector regex is working, btw.
Any clue as to what it is I'm screwing up?

MY thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I got it working by configuring service like this (names adapted to your case):

```
ExecStart=/opt/node_exporter/node_exporter --collector.systemd --collector.systemd.unit-include=(grafana|ssh).service
```

After doing so remember to reload your configuration via **systemctl daemon-reload** and restart your node exporter. After those steps on my config, when I check the metrics, I only get processes that I want. Hope it helps